# JavaScript doesn't work on Chrome 58 on Android in offline mode

Tags: chrome-for-android, javascript

I have a single-HTML web page with embedded `<script>` tags. When I view the offline version of this page in Chrome 58 on Android, JavaScript event handlers are not executed. (When I connect to the internet and reload the page, JavaScript starts working again.) How can I get my JavaScript back without a working internet connection on Chrome 58 on Android?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome offline pages do not support JavaScript.. You won't be able to get it to work in an offline page.. Maybe there are other browsers who do support JavaScript but I'm not sure.

Comment: is this documented somewhere, is a reason given why this is was disabled? Chrome can deal with javascript normaly, so why not offfline?